# Make multi checkbox getElementById with url link and change the link with value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have code like this... I want if I click checkbox for ex. hotel1, link `+check+` will change hotel1, and if I click checkbox hotel2, link `+check+` will change hotel2....
but the link not change...any idea?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function link() {
 var locationSearch = document.getElementById("locationSearchTerms").value;
 var textSearch = document.getElementById("textSearchTerms").value;
 var check = document.getElementsByName("checkbox1").value;
 window.location.href = "http://www.server12.com/ser2/"+check+"/?textSearchTerms="+textSearch+"&locationSearchTerms="+locationSearch+"";
 }
</script>
```

```html
<form id="search" method="get" class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-md-6">
     Destination:  
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex: Aston" name="textSearchTerms" id="textSearchTerms">
    
     Location:
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex:Denpasar" name="locationSearchTerms" id="locationSearchTerms">  &nbsp;  &nbsp;
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off"  onclick="link()"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"> Search</button>
        
     <br />
     <br />
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1"  value="Hotel">Hotel
        <label><br />
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1"  value="Hotel1">Hotel1
        <label><br />
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1"  value="Hotel2">Hotel2
        <label><br />
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1"  value="Hotel3">Hotel3
        <label><br />
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1"  value="Hotel4">Hotel4
        <label><br />
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1"  value="Hotel5">Hotel5
        <label><br />
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1"  value="Hotel5">Hotel6
        <label><br />

     </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Ids have to be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have same Id's to multiple elements in the DOM. It's a bad practise and is a pain if we are using Jquery. The problem is that when ever you are trying to get the value of the checbox by the code

```
var check = document.getElementsByName("checkbox1").value;
```

The result will always be the first element and its value. So make sure you are finding out the checbox which is checked and then retrieve its value.

```
var check = $('input[name="checkbox1"]:checked').val();
```

This should get you the right value. But if multiple checkboxes are checked then it will give the value of the first checked checkbox in the HTML hierarchy.

I would suggest using radio button if you are intending to use only one option selection for a search. I have made changes to your code with radio buttons and made some code changes. 
1) Removed onclick event from the button. And registered the event in jquery document ready.
2) Changed checkboxes to radio button.

Here is the [Working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/5nLj84at/)  Let me know if you want further help.

Comment: thank u for Answer but var check = $('input[name="checkbox1", checked="checked"]').val(); not work

Comment: Sorry I didn't have a chance to check it. Gimme some time, I'll help you out once I have access to my machine

Comment: And Let me confirm one thing, Should you have 1 checkbox checked at a time?? or are you intending to do multiple checkbox's being checked while searching??

Comment: 1 checkbox checked, not multi checkbox's

Comment: Did you check the fiddle link??

Comment: Hai @reddy I dont want alert function...I want the link change...tnaks

Comment: I just put alert to show you the link string.. You can just place the code in alert into your window.location and see the expected result

Comment: Your fiddle is not working beacuse you have not added the jquery library into it. I updated it and here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/ks42swbe/6/ . You can see the page trying to reload with new url but the browser might block it. Overall I can see it working no issues.